# How to add an image to word document and download using grails?

Tags: grails, doc

I use the code below to download image directly but I need to put it in word doc and want to download the doc.

```
        response.contentType = "application/octet-stream"
        response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=image.jpg")
        response.outputStream << inputstream
        response.outputStream.flush()
```

Can anyone know how to add an image to word document and download using grails?

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I guess Apache POI would allow you to add an image to a word doc http://poi.apache.org/

Comment: Thanks but I have found solution for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use http://blogs.bytecode.com.au/glen/2010/11/04/creating-word-docx-documents-dynamically-from-grails-or-java.html and http://blog.iprofs.nl/2012/10/22/adding-images-and-layout-to-your-docx4j-generated-word-documents-part-1/ to solve my code so I use docx4j for inserting image into word document using grails.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

as suggested by Dónal, Apache POI might be a solution. But you also might want to try the following approach:

- Create a word document with an image
- save it as xml
- create such an xml document in grails and replace the image with your own
- deliver it through grails with content-type "application/msword"

at least this works fine for excel files...

Comment: Thanks but what I want was for microsoft word and I have found solution for it.

Comment: Would you like to share your solution with us?

Comment: I did. Thanks anyways.